# How to delete a specific user's messages instantly?

Tags: python, discord.py

I am trying to code a command into my Discord Bot that when triggered will actively delete new messages from a specific user.

I have tried a couple variations of using ctx but I honestly I don't entirely understand how I could use it to accomplish this.

This block of code deletes the message that triggers it. Because of this, I think I am taking the wrong approach because it only deletes from whoever triggers it and only if they type the command. Obviously, I am new to this. I would appreciate any and all help. Thanks so much :)

```
@client.event
async def on_message(ctx):
    message_author = ctx.author.id
    if message_author == XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX:
        await ctx.message.delete()
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no more CTX in discord rewrite (DiscordPy 1.0+) instead you should do:

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author.id == XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX:
        await message.delete()
```

Source: [link](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/api.html#discord.on_message)

Answer (score 0):

You can make a command to add the users to a list then use `on_message` to check if a user is in that list and then delete it if true

```py
dels=[]

@bot.event
async def on_message(msg):
    if msg.author.id in dels:
        await bot.delete_message(msg)

    await bot.process_commands(msg)


@bot.command(name='del_msg')
async def delete_message(con,*users:discord.Member):
    for i in users:
        dels.append(i.id)

    await con.send("Users {} have been added to delete messages list".format(" ,".join(users)))
```